# apllying $watch over a list of scope variables

Tags: angularjs

i have some scope variables like 'a1,a2,a3,a4,...an', I want to apply $watch over all this scope variables.Is it possible to apply this in single watch function like shown below.

```
var list=['a1','a2','a3',...,'an']
for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    $scope.$watch(list[i],function(){
     alert(list[i]+'changed');
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you using it with ng-repeat?

Comment: yes, I'm using it with ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

what you have there is not a single watch function it will actually create a function for each element in the array, and yes that should work now if you really want to have a single function and you don't care about who changed or its value you could do something like

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){ 
     var list=['a1','a2','a3',...,'an'];
     values="";
     angular.forEach(list,function(item){
          values+=($scope[item])+'_';
     })
     return values;
   },function(){
       //do something here with the values

    })
```

this works if there are all values if you where to have objects to watch you'll need to do JSON.stringify to the variables to get their state. also this solution only applies if knowing who changed is irrelevant for the operation to perform i.e calculating a total, ratio, or sanity checking on what should be constant values

Answer (score 0):

When using ng-repeat you can assign a controller for each element (nice huh!)

if you have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-controller="ElementController"></div>
```

You can watch it like this:

```
angular.module(...).controller('ElementController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('element.some_name', function (someName) {

    });
});
```

This controller should stil be able to access the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection):

```
$scope.list = ['a1','a2','a3',...,'an'];
$scope.$watchCollection('list', function(newList, oldList){...});
```

Or just use the regular `$watch` with an array:

```
$scope.$watch('[a1, a2,...]', function(newList, oldList){...});
```

Comment: Your ans is correct. but what if we want to check which element's value is changed and if want to display the same element's value new and old values?

Comment: `$watchCollection` passes the new and old collections as arguments to the listener function, so I guess you can compare them. but it's not an ideal solution

Comment: No it doesn't i guess. it just tells you whether newValue==oldValue or not. but what if you want to trace changed element? would be nice if you could help.

Comment: You can compare it, the listener function should be passed as a second argument (not the first) but it can only compare the two arrays. not a single element in that array

Comment: @micronyks, the listener function in both methods will get as arguments the new list and the old list, so you can iterate through both list and compare them.